# How to increase the pixel/resolution of jsPDF downloaded pdf file

Tags: php, jspdf

Below code of **jsPDF** is working fine but when it downloads the pdf file the resolution/pixels are very poor images and text is blur.

How can we increase the pixels/resolutions of the jsPDF downloaded file.

```
function completedsx_<?php echo $ohhz['order_id']; ?>() {

var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML($("#content<?php echo $ohhz['order_id']; ?>")[0], function() {
pdf.save('Invoice_<?php echo $ohhz['order_id']; ?>.pdf');
});
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/issues/39

Comment: @IVOGELOV no use of this tried it

Comment: Another one - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/339

Comment: Can u please make fix within my code? @IVOGELOV

Comment: I would instead suggest to look for server-side solutions like PrinceXML or PhantomJS - you will certainly get much better PDFs.